# subprocess мультипроцессовость?

Tags: python

Такой код:

```
import subprocess
import random
pas = ''
for x in range(3): #Количество символов (3)
    pas = pas + random.choice(list('1234567890'))
cmd = str(subprocess.check_output(['ping', '-c', f'{pas}', 'google.com'], text=True))
```

Как запустить указанное число прроцессов 'ping' одновременно, указав для каждого уникальную переменную {pas}?